# Pyodbc connection to SQL Server failed - neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to make an insertion to my SQL Server database by using pyodbc. But I can never achieve it. Please help me.

By the way; I defined `index_pred_as_int` in previous code snippet.

My code:

```
import pyodbc 

server = 'DESKTOP-T7OFQV6\SQLEXPRESS1'
database = 'VidgaEmotionRecognition'

#defining connection string
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; \\\
                       SERVER=' + server + '; \\\
                       DATABASE=' + database +';\\\
                       Trusted_Connection=yes;')

#creating the connection cursor
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

#defining insert query
insert_query='''INSERT INTO FaceEmotion (emotion)
                VALUES (?);'''

#defining insertion value
values = index_pred_as_int

#insert the data
cursor.execute(insert_query, values)

#commit the insertion
cnxn.commit()

#grab the database table values
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM FaceEmotion')

#printing the results
for values in cursor:
    print(values)
```

And here's the error:

> OperationalError
>
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> in 
> 18 #defining connection string
> ---> 19 cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; \\
> 20  SERVER=' + server + '; \\
> 21                        DATABASE=' + database +';\\
>
> OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand how the `\\\` are supposed to work, but I think they are breaking it. I set up a similar connection on my computer and used your same connection string and got the same error. When I put the whole connection string on one line, it seems to work just fine.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database +';Trusted_Connection=yes')
```

Edit: it also appears to work just fine if you use just one `\` to divide your line, instead of that triple.

Comment: Thanks so much mate! You just saved me there.